# Pass custom parameters to subactivity

Tags: android

Is there any way to pass custom parameters from a activity to a sub-activity?

I tried to do it via a constructor by creating a object of the sub-activity in the main-activity and passing the desired parameters. But when i start the sub-activity via a Intent the program fails.

The parameter I'm trying to pass is the main-activity.

Thanks for all response!

Answer (score 2):

Put extras on the `Intent` you pass to `startActivity()`. You will find a series of `putExtra()` methods, and corresponding getters, on the `Intent` class. Your "sub-activity" can call `getIntent()` to retrieve the `Intent` used to start it, and from there get at the extras.